# How to close the search box in Firefox with a keyboard shortcut when this box is out of focus?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox, by Ctrl+F a small search box is opened and one can search through the page.

If this box is still under focus, by `ESC` on can close it.
But if this box is out of focus (for example if one clicks on some place of the webpage) the shortcut `ESC` for closing it does not work.

How to close this search box in this situation with a keyboard shortcut (i.e. without using the mouse)?

To be precise I use Firefox 49.0.1 on Win7.

Answer (score 5):

Press Ctrl+F again and then `ESC`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to put the find bar back in focus with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then close it with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The add-on [FindBar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search) offers an option to close the find bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> when it is unfocussed.

Comment: Indeed. FindBar Tweak can also "Close the Findbar when it loses focus"

Comment: Thanks the option "Close the Findbar when it loses focus" in FindBar Tweak can close the Findbar when it loses focus.

Comment: This worked for me with Vimperator installed.