# Ctrl+F+Esc won't close find bar in Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I was looking for a keyboard shortcut to close the find bar in Firefox 49.0 on Ubuntu and arrived to this question:

[How to close the search box in Firefox with a keyboard shortcut when this box is out of focus?](https://superuser.com/q/1129624/63373)

However, for some reason <kbd>Esc</kbd> won't close the Find bar even if it has the focus. It's a bit annoying when one wants to refocus on the web content.

Is there any special setting I am not aware of that's preventing me from using the normal workflow?

Comment: Use [Find Bar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search). Hitting <ctrl>+<f> will toggle the find bar regardless of whether it has focus (on Windows anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For some reason <kbd>Esc</kbd> won't close the Find Bar even if it has the focus.

Download and install the [Find Bar Tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search) extension.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will toggle the Find Bar regardless of whether it has focus.

Tested and working on Windows, I presume it will work on Linux as well.

Comment: This also works great with Vimperator installed - that grabs the `ESC` and stops the bar from closing.

Comment: @jamesc Great! :)