# Show number of find matches

Tags: vimperator

When searching for text on a webpage with Firefox, without Vimperator, each match is shown on the status bar as '1 of 9', '2 of 9', as each is highlighted.

When using Vimperator, no such detail is provided. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default search in Vimperator is not ideal and I don't think there's a pure Vimperator way to solve this at the moment.

You can still get this information from the Firefox internal search (which I think carries out the search function). Once your search is triggered, you can press <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Firefox search box which will show you the "1 of 2 Matches" information.

It can be hard to close the search dialogue box. I've installed the [Find Bar Tweak extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search) as recommended by [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1136118/ctrlfesc-wont-close-find-bar-in-firefox/1136541) - it works well with Vimperator. This also helps by highlighting the search match and marks them in the scroll bar on the right hand side.